# Maven - Possible to generate surefire report before timeout?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a large suite of tests that run in a CI/CD environment. Due to the size of these tests and the fact that some are likely to fail due to flakiness and actual problems, I have set up my maven command to retry all failing tests twice. However, to help keep costs down, I have also set up a timeout on the CI/CD pipeline such that no job can run over a set amount of time (3 hours). In most cases, my test suite completes in around 45 minutes. However, when running my tests, there are times when the number of retries increases the testing run time to the limit and the operation shuts down. At this point, maven did not get to finish its testing and surefire does not generate a report. Essentially, if the tests hit the pipeline time limit, I cannot know which tests failed. Since the execution of these tests ended abruptly, it does not appear that running `mvn surefire-report:report-only` will generate the report.

My current maven command is as follows:

`mvn surefire-report:report -pl :api-integration-tests -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2-temp/repository -DshowSuccess=false -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DskipIntegrationTests=false -Dsandbox=true --batch-mode`

Is there a way to have surefire or maven generate the results of the test as they are running such that if test execution is suddenly stopped, I would still be able to see my results? Alternatively, is it possible to send some sort of command (kill or otherwise) that would gracefully stop the test execution and generate the surefire report based on the current state? I do not want to simply end the execution of the tests upon a single failure, I'd like to see all the failures of the current execution. I am running the maven command via a bash script. The CI/CD pipeline is via GitLab.

Comment: Really wondering what the value would be of the intermediate test report. Are you going to dig through that to separate flaky tests from real regressions? For that matter, what is the value of this test suite anyway? You're bordering on the point that a manager should halt all development and make the team reduce the flakiness. I think that in serious "CI" there's little role for `rerunFailingTestsCount` anyway. Sorry, this is probably mostly off-topic for the question, but maybe fires you up enough to go kick some cans internally. Good luck.

Comment: Back, here, for a slightly more constructive comment. Thinking about how 45 minutes is counter to the "Keep the build fast" practice. I've dealt with that problem before by breaking it up in parallel builds. It's cheating, we all just need smaller overall builds, but alas, if in a pinch, it helps. I've done this before by assigning each parallel build a portion of the test cases (e.g. using suites, or simply using wildcards on parts of the alphabet). A shorter overall build is, but (toward your question) it also lets you fail portions of the build separately, while still reporting on others.

Comment: To answer your first comment, because I have so many tests, it's difficult to know which ones have failed, and yes, I'll be going through all failures to figure out which ones are real. Most of the time, there is a single underlying cause that once I fix, the tests all work again. But without knowing which tests are failing, I can't begin a fix. As to your second comment, this build runs in the background on all branches while I work on other tasks. It doesn't need to be short since I don't notice it running anyway.